SQLAlchemy Operator with those arguments doesn't exist
I have class GroupORM that presents table in DB
class GroupORM(Base):
    __tablename__ = "group"

    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(server_default=func.now())

    users: Mapped[List["UserORM"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="groups", lazy="selectin"
    )

And also I have the class for working with my DB. The short form looks like that:
class GroupRepository:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.db = f"postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}"
        self.session = Session(create_engine(self.db, echo=True, client_encoding='utf8'))
    def get_group(self, group_id: UUID):
        with self.session as sess:
            return sess.query(GroupORM).filter(GroupORM.id == group_id).first()


But when I try to create an entity using method get_group I have the following error:
    group = GroupRepository()
    group_obj = group.get_group(uuid.UUID("efb3a0dd-40f7-4104-9d12-16cd8bbfd064"))

 WHERE user_table.group_id IN ('efb3a0dd-40f7-4104-9d12-16cd8...

Why is my code trying to find Id in user_table and not in group?
I tried to rename my tables, but it doesn't work
When I do query in sql shell everything is good

There is no IN clause in the get_group method in the question. Please [edit] the question to include an [mre] and the complete error message and traceback.
